# Display list of checkboxes with different Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a list of checkboxes with pre-saved values.

I want to display this list to check the checked ones , an uncheck the non-checked ones.

I use JqueryMobile.

```
function CheckExistingDays(DayId, DaysList, DayName)
        {
            var Len = DaysList.length;
            var FoundLessCounter = 0;
            for(var i =0;i<Len;i++)
             {
                 //alert("Day Id is : "+ DayId+" Day At List is "+ DaysList[i]);
                 if(DayId== DaysList[i])
                 {
                     $("#WeekDays fieldset").append('<input type="checkbox" name="'+ DayName+'" CheckboxId="'+ DayId +'" id="cool'+ i +'" class="custom" checked /><label for="cool'+ i +'">'+ DayName +'</label>');

                 }

                 else
                 {
                     FoundLessCounter++;
                     if(FoundLessCounter == Len)
                     {
                         $("#WeekDays fieldset").append('<input type="checkbox" name="'+ DayName+'" CheckboxId="'+ DayId +'" id="cool'+ i +'" class="custom"/><label for="cool'+ i +'">'+ DayName +'</label>');
                     }

                 }

             }



        }
```

Where DaysList contains the saved values.

The Checked boxes are correctly displayed but the unchecked boxes are displayed in a worng way : 
[image: CheckBoxes View]

But one of the days that should be checked is also output with the wrong ones, it just has a right mark beside it.

So, is there a method where I can fix this code ?

Comment: hard to guess without more code. try wrapping the checkbox in the <label> tag and changing 'checked' attribute to 'checked="checked"' `<label for="cool'+ i +'"><input type="checkbox" name="'+ DayName+'" CheckboxId="'+ DayId +'" id="cool'+ i +'" class="custom" checked="checked"/>'+ DayName +'</label>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the "i" counter at the id.

At the Unchecked Days it wasn't incremented correctly, so I just changed this:

```
                $("#WeekDays fieldset").append('<input type="checkbox" id="cool'+ i +'" class="custom" checked /><label for="cool'+ i +'">'+ DayName +'</label>');
```

to

```
               $("#WeekDays fieldset").append('<input type="checkbox" id="cool'+ DayId+'" class="custom" checked /><label for="cool'+ DayId +'">'+ DayName +'</label>');
```

And everything was fixed when the id was corrected :) 
`